# Find $a$ and $b$ knowing that $S\cup T=\{-1,1,2,3\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers.
>
> $S$ is solution set for the following equation : 
>   $$(1):\ x^{2}+ax+b=0$$
>   $T$ is solution set for the following equation : 
>   $$(2):\ x^{2}-bx+a=0$$
>   Find $a$ and $b$  knowing that $S\cup T=\{-1,1,2,3\}$

My thoughts:

- for the equation $(1)$ her discriminant is $\Delta_{1}=a^{2}-4b$
- for the equation $(2)$ her discriminant is $\Delta_{2}=b^{2}-4a$

the two equations admitting solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ iff $a^{2}-4b >0$ and $b^{2}-4a>0$ and $\dfrac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^{2}-4b}}{2}\in\{ -1,1,2,3 \}$ and $\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4a}}{2}\in\{-1,1,2,3 \}$

or we can work with :
$P(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$  roots $x_1, x_2$ of the equation $P(x)=0$ satisfy
$$x_1 + x_2 = - \frac{b}{a}, \quad x_1 x_2 = \frac{c}{a}.$$

Answer (score 3):

write the equations in factors:
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$$
$$(x-x_3)(x-x_4)=0$$
If you work this out you get
$$x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2=0$$
$$x^2-(x_3+x_4)x+x_3x_4=0$$

So what you want is
$$-(x_1+x_2)=x_3x_4$$
$$x_3+x_4=x_3x_4$$

since $-(1+2)=-1\cdot 3$  and $-1+3=1\cdot 2$ we have appropriate values for the roots. plug these into the equations above to find $a$ and $b$

$$a=-(1+2)=-3$$
$$b=-1+3=2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_1$, $c_2$ be the solutions of $x^2 + ax+b=0$ and $d_1$, $d_2$ the solutions of $x^2-bx+a$.

Vieta's formulas tell us that for the solutions $K_1$, $K_2$ of $x^2 -Sx+P=$ we have
$$K_1+K_2=S$$
$$K_1 \cdot K_2=P$$

When you apply that to your given equations we have that
$$c_1+c_2=-a$$
$$c_1 \cdot c_2=b$$
and
$$d_1+d_2=b$$
$$d_1 \cdot d_2=a$$
So you need
$$c_1+c_2 = -d_1 \cdot d_2$$
$$c_1 \cdot c_2=d_1+d_2$$

You can see that the pairs that satisfy those equations are 
$(-1,3)$ and $(1,2)$
Therefore $a=-3$, $b=2$

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the two pairs

Comment: It is trivial by inspection, if you try all the combinations of $\{ -1,1,2,3 \}$ you will see that those combinations satisfy the last two equations, so those are the ones you need!

Answer (score 0):

You want two roots whose sum equals the product of the other two (both = b). So you need 3 + (-1) = 2 x 1. Check: $(x-3)(x+1)=x^2-2x-3,(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$. Or put another way, $a=-3,b=2$.